# Implementing Interface in Excel VBA from C# Library

Tags: c#, vba, excel, dll

I am completely new to VBA. What I am trying to do is to use a C# DLL that is COM-enabled in order to add some functionality to Excel.

In my DLL I have an event mechanism that is dependent on an Interfaces to implement the event functionality. One of the Interfaces looks like this:

```
public interface IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener
{
    String GadgetActivated();
    String GadgetActivationFailed(String response);
}
```

I am trying to implement this as a class Module in Excel. The code is the following:

```
Implements IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener

Public Function IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivated() As String
     MsgBox ("hello")
     IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivated = ""
End Function

Public Function IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivationFailed(response As String) As String
     MsgBox (response)
     IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivationFailed = response
End Function
```

When I try to compile the module, I get

> Compile Error: procedure declaration does not match description of
>   event or procedure having the same name

The interface is OK I think because If I omit one of the methods I get the message:

> Compile error:
>   Object module needs to implement 'GadgetActivationFailed' for
>   interface 'ClsInterface' OK/Help

Also I can create objects with the classes of the DLL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever get this thing to work? I am having the exact same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and was able to resolve it by annotating the function parameter with `ByVal`. In your case it would be:

```vb
Implements IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener

Public Function IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivated() As String
     MsgBox ("hello")
     IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivated = ""
End Function

Public Function IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivationFailed(ByVal response As String) As String
     MsgBox (response)
     IActivateGadgetResponseActionListener_GadgetActivationFailed = response
End Function
```